# Difficulty of porting a TCP client and server from Linux to QNX Neutrino

Tags: porting, qnx, qnx-neutrino

Are there any major differences between a modern Linux and QNX Neutrino that would make porting an existing client/server difficult?  The source is normally built using Qt's qmake, but has no other Qt dependencies.

I need to provide an estimate for how long this process will take, but I've never used QNX.

If it matters, this will run on an ARM CPU, but we already build for ARM on Linux as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really going to be hard to estimate until you try because there are a lot of similarities, but where there are differences can be more problematic.  If I were estimating, I would start by downloading an eval copy of the QNX and try building to see what problems you are facing.

The biggest issue may have is if you are using a GUI.  QNX uses it's own GUI technology which is not X.  (Although Qt 4.7 has been ported to QNX 6.5, so if you were to use Qt, it would probably work.)

Comment: Thankfully we aren't using a GUI.